# Is this $3\times3$ matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

After browsing through similar posts, I was wondering if I am understanding the meaning of "$n$ distinct eigenvalues" for the following theorem.

> If the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then the corresponding eigenvectors are linearly independent and $A$ is diagonalizable.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\lambda I - A = 0 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda - 3 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & \lambda - 0 & -2 \\
0 & -2 & \lambda - 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
(\lambda - 3)\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda & -2 \\
-2 & \lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}
= 
(\lambda - 3) (\lambda ^ 2 - 4 )
$

I get $\lambda = 3, 2, -2$. I tried to find an eigenvector with $\lambda = 3$ and got a weird looking matrix that doesn't look linearly independent. Despite this weird matrix, I rearranged the rows via column operations and managed to find an eigenvector. It appears the matrix is diagonalizable? I am not sure I handled $\lambda = 3$ correctly though.
$3I - A 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 3 & -2 \\
0 & -2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}  
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}  
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0x_2 + 0x_3 \\
0x_3 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
x_3 \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$2I - A 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & -2 \\
0 & -2 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}  
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
3_x3 \\
-x_3 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
x_3 \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$-2I - A 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
-5 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & -2 & -2 \\
0 & -2 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -.2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}  
\rightarrow  
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
-.2x_3 \\
x_3 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
x_3 \begin{bmatrix}
.2 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -3 & .2 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, 
$P^{-1}AP = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 1.4e^{-13} \\
-.5 & 2 & 0 \\
-2.5 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: you forgot a $-2$ in the right member of the equation

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: $2 \neq -2$ so you have three distinct eigenvalues.  In your title, why not use $3$ instead of $n$?  There is no $n$ in the problem except in the statement of the theorem which you are specializing to $n=3$

Comment: I changed the phrasing of my question as you are right, there are 3 eigenvalues (3,2,-2)

Comment: The first eigenvector should be $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the first eigenvector:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
gives $x_2=0$ and $x_3=0$, with $x_1$ free; thus an eigenvector is
\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
You cannot transform it into
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is a very different linear system.

Comment: what makes $x_1$ (first column of 0s) free and not $x_3$ free (last row of 0s)?

Comment: @EvanKim The unknowns correspond to columns, not to rows

Comment: what are you referring to as the unknowns?

Comment: @EvanKim You are solving the system $\begin{bmatrix}0&-2&-1\\0&3&-2\\0&-2&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ for the unknowns $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.

Comment: Is it wrong that I had the unknowns correspond to the rows when I solved $\lambda = 2, -2$? Or did I solve the unknowns correctly, but did so for the wrong reason? (I think the unknowns correspond to the rows, not columns in those instances).

Comment: @EvanKim The solutions were correct, but probably for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 2):

You have three eigenvalues; $\lambda^2-4$ has roots of both $2$ and $-2$.

Additionally, it is not the matrices that will be independent, but the eigenvectors. That "weird" matrix is going to tell you what the eigenvector associated with $\lambda=3$ is, as soon as you find its nullspace.

Comment: I thought to solve, you do $\lambda ^2 = 4$. And that reduces down to $\lambda = 2$. OH because it's a square root, it would be +/- 2

Comment: @EvanKim Correct!

Comment: I found all the eigenvectors and it appears that the matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: @EvanKim Well it has to be, doesn't it? You had three distinct eigenvalues, and your theorem told you that would promise diagonalizability.

Comment: Okay. I guess the basis for my initial question is no longer there after you pointed out that there are three eigenvalues....everything still seemed to work out properly